# Svelte get all properties on current svelte file

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

How to get all properties on current svelte file?

for example this `Component1.svelte`

```html
<script>
  let x = '';
  let y = '';
  let z = '';

  onMount(function(){
    console.log( what? ); 
    // need to print x, y, and z which set by other code
    // that using/importing this file
    // without defining one by one, was there such property?
  });
</script>
<span>{x}</span>
<div>{y}</div>
<p>{z}</p>
```

Used by `whatever.svelte`

```html
<script>
   import Foo from `./Component1.svelte`
</script>
<Foo x="1" y="abc">test</Foo>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$$props` for this, it will return all properties passed on to the component.

Comment: And you’ll have all properties without `export`declaration by `$$restProps`: https://svelte.dev/docs#Attributes_and_props